# Read xml data in format :Sql server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have xml data as following:

```
<GProposal>
 <UnderwritingMessages>
                            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">3425：入院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
                            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">3428：通院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
                 </UnderwritingMessages>
    <Plans>
        <Plan>
          <UnderwritingMessages />
               <InsuredGroups>
                        <InsuredGroup>
                          <UnderwritingMessages>
                            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342025：入院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
                            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342028：通院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
                 </UnderwritingMessages>
                   <Description>役員・事業主</Description>
                          <InsuredGroupType>1</InsuredGroupType>
                </InsuredGroup>
             <InsuredGroup>
                      <UnderwritingMessages>
                        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342025：入院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
                        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342028：通院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
                      </UnderwritingMessages>
             </InsuredGroup>
          </InsuredGroups>
     </Plan>
    </Plans>
</GProposal>
```

Insured group can have max of 4 and plans can have max of 3 how do I need to fetch using loop.

I am using the below format to fetch the following values.

```
select distinct P.proposalid as 'Proposal Id',
     (CASE WHEN p2.XMLData.value('count(/Plans/Plan/InsuredGroups/InsuredGroup/UnderwritingMessages/*)', 'int') > 0 THEN
                (SELECT TOP 1 T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS result  
                    FROM p2.XMLData.nodes('(/*/Plans/Plan/InsuredGroups/InsuredGroup/UnderwritingMessages)') T(c))
         ELSE
                (SELECT TOP 1 T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS result  
                    FROM p2.XMLData.nodes('(/*/UnderwritingMessages)') T(c))
    END) as UWReferralComment

from proposal P
-- referred before
cross APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ProposalId , Starteffectivedate,Data as XMLData
     FROM Proposal
    WHERE ProposalId = P.ProposalId
    AND ProposalTypeID = 1
    AND ProposalStatusID = 3
    AND EndEffectiveDate <> '21991231'
    --and  len(isnull(Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="uc7_UWApprovalNum"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),'') ) > 0
) P2
```

Output :
[image]
I need to combine all the UnderwritingMessages tags to show as string with out duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear... The XML provided is not well-formed (missing `xsi` namespace), your own `SELECT` seems to be overcomplicated and I cannot see the reason for your sub-select, nor can I follow your `XQuery`, which mentions a path not visible in the provided XML.

You can try the following:

A *mock-up* table to simulate your access:

```
DECLARE @proposal TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,XmlData XML);
INSERT INTO @proposal VALUES
(N'<GProposal xmlns:xsi="dummy">
  <UnderwritingMessages>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">3425：入院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">3428：通院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
  </UnderwritingMessages>
  <Plans>
    <Plan>
      <UnderwritingMessages />
      <InsuredGroups>
        <InsuredGroup>
          <UnderwritingMessages>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342025：入院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342028：通院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
          </UnderwritingMessages>
          <Description>役員・事業主</Description>
          <InsuredGroupType>1</InsuredGroupType>
        </InsuredGroup>
        <InsuredGroup>
          <UnderwritingMessages>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342025：入院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">342028：通院補償一時金が引受限度額を超えています。引受照会が必要です。</anyType>
          </UnderwritingMessages>
        </InsuredGroup>
      </InsuredGroups>
    </Plan>
  </Plans>
</GProposal>');
```

--This query will provide you with a template for any value somewhere within your XML using hierarchically nested `.nodes()` calls. I assume, that `<Plans><Plan>` point to a `1:n` hierarchy as well as `<InsuredGroups><InsuredGroup>`. Furthermore it looks, as if any level may have `<UnderwritingMessages>`:

```
SELECT TopMessages.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TopMessage
      ,B.pl.value(N'(SomeValueHere)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS SomeValueOnPlanLevel
      ,B1.at.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS MessageOnPlanLevel
      ,C.ig.value(N'(SomeValueHere)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS SomeValueOnGroupLevel
      ,C1.at.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS MessageOnGroupLevel
FROM @proposal AS p
OUTER APPLY p.XmlData.nodes(N'/GProposal/UnderwritingMessages/anyType') AS A(TopMessages)
OUTER APPLY p.XmlData.nodes(N'/GProposal/Plans/Plan') AS B(pl)
OUTER APPLY pl.nodes(N'UnderwritingMessages/anyType') AS B1(at)
OUTER APPLY pl.nodes(N'InsuredGroups/InsuredGroup') AS C(ig)
OUTER APPLY ig.nodes(N'UnderwritingMessages/anyType') AS C1(at);
```

But if I take your question literally:

> I need to combine all the UnderwritingMessages tags to show as string with out duplicates.

...this might be enough:

```
SELECT msg.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS UnderwritingMessage
      ,msg.value(N'local-name(../..)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Location
FROM @proposal AS p
OUTER APPLY p.XmlData.nodes(N'//anyType') AS A(msg);
```

You can use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to get a result *without duplicates*.

### UPDATE

After consulting my magic crystal ball I've got the impression you are looking for something called *string aggregation*. Version 2016+ offers `STRING_AGG`, but with your version you will need to do something like this:

```
SELECT ID
      ,STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + msg.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
        FROM p.XmlData.nodes(N'//UnderwritingMessages/anyType') AS A(msg)
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS UWReferralComment
FROM @proposal AS p;
```

`ID` is representing any "normal" column of your table, add the columns you need. The sub-select will read all messages from the xml and concatenate them in one big string separated by a comma.

Comment: when I use the below query to combine and return as one string it's not working, it combines only the first node text of UnderwritingMessages.but I need to combine all the text related to all the UnderwritingMessages nodes.

Comment: @Kapil No idea what you are talking about ... Please post the expected output

Comment: I have already the attached the screen shot of output in the question.Please refer the last column in the screenshot UWReferralComment I need to display all the underwritingmessages text in the entire xml and display like the screenshot.

Comment: When I execute your query :SELECT msg.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS UnderwritingMessage
      ,msg.value(N'local-name(../..)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Location
FROM @proposal AS p
OUTER APPLY p.XmlData.nodes(N'//anyType') AS A(msg);                                                         I was not able to return all the nodes associated with Underwritermessages in the entire xml.                                                   I need to concatenate all the messges of nodes Underwritermessages in the entire xml I have provided in the question.